# Advice on database structure for a mysql forum needed

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a forum where every topic can have a set of tags(like the tags on stack overflow). I'm storing each topic as a row in a table that has columns for storing timestamp, title, description, etc.

What would be the best way for storing each question's tags in the mysql database preferably using php only? Should I create a new table for each topic and store the tags on seperate rows in that table? I'm sure there are more efficient ways. Please help.

Performance is an issue. And I must also be able to retrieve all the topics that belong to a particular tag.

Comment: Apart from the way you described... can you think of another way you could do it?

Comment: if you worry about performance then do all stored procedures and just feed the prams into it, I think that should help alot.

Comment: @putvande, I can't. That is why I'm asking this question to know if there are better ways.

Comment: Just create 1:M table, store topic_id and tag, job done. Why complicate simple things for christs' sake..

Comment: @N.B. every topic can have multiple tags. Not just one. Hope you understand now why i need to complicate things.

Comment: That's why you create the one to many relation. One topic_id, different tags, multiple rows. It's not hard.

Comment: It is a many-to-many relationship, as I see it

Comment: If there is one piece of advice I would give, it would be to look into an alternative to mysql as your database. This is especially true if you want better performance. There are a lot of open source/free options out there. I'm a huge fan of postgres, but there are plenty of other good options.

Comment: I was about to post a great answer, oh well.

Comment: @MrGlass - if there is one piece of advice I'd like to give is to stop being a fan boy and suggest dumb "advices". What you wrote is full of bias and only terrible wannabe developers opt to hand out advices like that.

Comment: @N.B. Yes, I am "biased" against mysql. Based on years of experience. Man asked an opinion based question, i gave an opinion based answer.

Comment: @MrGlass - it's irrelevant if you're biased, there's no proof of your capability whatsoever so what you *think* is irrelevant if there are *facts* proving otherwise, nor do you know the costs of swapping development stack. Suggesting things like that is a sign of a horrible developer. It's one thing to suggest an alternative *learning* platform opposed to replacing the stack mid-development.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to create a separate table just for the tags and then link it to the other one by creating a column in the new one that references the Topics' ids in the first. This way if wouldn't make the original table a mess and you can still set topics for each of the tags. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it might not be a good idea. It **is** the only way to do it properly. Don't be afraid to point out proper ways. Have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your shoud use two tables.

`Tag` - table to store tags
`Topic2Tag` - to store relation betwen tags and topic

so your system will get max flexibility

Or you can store tags in one column of topic table separated by comma, but if later you wil try to do something whith tags .... "this is heavy"